# reducer state update errors on array in typescript class with redux-toolkit

Tags: typescript, redux-toolkit, immer.js

I'm using redux-toolkit and need to update a state member after an frontend actions. The structure looks like that: state.theMap: `{ string: { string: ClassA } }`. Something like:

```
{
  "keyA": { "keyAA": ClassA, "keyAB": ClassA },
  "keyB": { "keyBA": ClassA, "keyBB": ClassA },
  ...
}
```

So a map of another map with some typescript class (lets call it ClassA) and the end of it. ClassA has an array (arrayA) of string has a member: `this.arrayA = ["a", "b", "c"]`; for example.

First in the reducer I'm getting the good map and if I find it I call removeIndex on it.

```
changeContentOfMap: (state, action) => {
  const { firstKey, secondKey, indexToRemove } = action.payload;
  const classAInstance = get(state.theMap, [firstKey, secondKey]);
  if (classAInstance) {
    classAInstance.removeIndexes(indexToRemove);
  }
}
```

In ClassA, I have a removeIndexes method to remove stuff in the array. I'm using a lodash pullAt call: `pullAt(this.arrayA, indexes)`.

Bear with me, this is of course oversimplified since I can't really share the real code. This works well if I'm doing it outside of reducers for the same values. But as soon, as I'm am in reducer, I get an error in pullAt, which is using a splice on the array: "Cannot delete property '0' of [object Array]". If I force and array copy before the pullAt: `pullAt(...this.arrayA, indexes)`: no problem.

I'm sure it has something to do with immer which is use by redux-toolkit in the background. I've put this[immerable] = true; in my typescript class I even tried to do a produce function to see if that was the problem, something like:

```
  removeIndexesWithImmer = (indexes: string[]): void => {
    produce(this, (draft) => {
      return draft.removeIndexes(indexes);
    });
  };
```

But nothing really works, execpt recreating ClassA and cloning the array inside it. Which is not what I want to do.

I'm surely missing something. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Digging further. I use isDraft from immer. ClassA is a draft, but what is inside it is frozen. So isDraft(classAInstance) -> true, but isDraft(classAInstance.arrayA) -> false. I don't really get it. I'm trying to use produce inside the class, but modifying this.arrayA is not possible: this.arrayA = produce(this.arrayA, (draftArrayA) => blablabla); The only way is to clone the whole thing.